# Deco M5 mesh with ethernet backhaul

Tags: switch, mesh-networking

I have a 3-node Deco M5 setup + 2 switches, more or less like this:

[image]

The problem seems to be the TL-SG108 switch. Once I connect it to the network, the entire network becomes unstable, sometimes right away, sometimes after a couple of hours.

I also tried something like this:

[image]

But it renders the same results.

I read somewhere that the Deco M5 requires uses IEEE1905.1, but it seems impossible to find on docs, product pages, etc, which switches support that and which ones doesn't.

My guess is that something's related to that is not working properly in the SG108, but I don't know how to confirm.

So, I think my questions are:

1. How can I know if the lack of proper IEEE1905.1 on the SG108 support is causing the issues on my network?
2. In case it isn't that, how can I find out what is causing the problems?
3. How can I find out if a given switch supports IEEE1905.1?

Answer (score 1):

> but it seems impossible to find on docs, product pages, etc, which switches support IEEE1905.1 and which ones doesn't.

The [IEEE1905.1 standard](https://standards.ieee.org/standard/1905_1-2013.html) says:

> Modification to the underlying home networking technologies is not required by the 1905.1 layer, and hence it does not change the behavior or implementation of existing home networking technologies.

So as long as the switch does not **interfere** with it in an incompatible way (which your switch UI should tell you, and it should also allow to turn that off), my understanding is that all switches should work with it.

> Once I connect it to the network, the entire network becomes unstable, sometimes right away

Did you try to contact TP-Link support? It's their hardware and firmware, they should know.

And even if you start debugging this (first think I'd do is take one or multiple laptops, run Wireshark and figure out what's going over the wire), you'll likely won't be able to fix it, as you don't have the firmware source.

Comment: hmm, yeah, my switches are not managed... so there's no UI to change anything... I think the SG180 might be "broken" somehow. I have already contacted their support as well, but they are very slow to reply... wireshark was also my first thought, but I wonder if there's an easier way. Thanks!